# Show previously selected cells by default when view opens, UICollectionView

Tags: iphone, ios

I am creating a seat map, there are few seats already booked and others can be, So, i need to show the already booked seats and available seats by different colors. Below is my code i am using to show selected and deselected cells, but how to make show already booked cells selected already.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
NSLog(@"indexpath row:%d", indexPath.row);
int v;
NSString *cnt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrSeats objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
v = [cnt intValue];
if(indexPath.item < v)
{
        if(cell.selected){
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yelow_seat.png"]];  // highlight selection
        }
        else
        {
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_seat.png"]]; // Default color
        }

        }else{
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blank_seat.png"]];
}
return cell;
}
```

Below is the code i am trying to use to add values for each section. Each time array add values for a section it adds it into dictionary then clears the array and again next time the array add values for next section and and put to dictionary, but dictionary not holding the value when array objects removed.

```
arrStatus = arrSeatsStatus;
        [seatsDict setObject:arrStatus forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
        i++;
        [arrSeatsStatus removeAllObjects];
```

I am having an array that holds the status of all seats as on or off, but how to implement it am not getting. Please guide for above.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

check this link  for cell highlighting

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCellsandViews/CreatingCellsandViews.html

or do one this create a label or imageview for cell and do the checking whether the corresponding element  is matching with your array element and then check their status ,if its matching then put some image or assign color over that item if its not matching leave it empty.

If it not working please let me i will help you

Comment: i have already tried this and working on it, if still problem comes will let you know soon.

Comment: i am getting problem in adding status values in array, as all values are section vise. SO, i am trying to add array containing values for each section in dictionary, means for each section there is an array. how to get it?

Comment: can u explain with an example